# How to install CharlesProxy ssl cerificate in Android

Tags: android, ssl, charles-proxy

I am connecting Mobile device with System via Proxy and capturing calls made in the mobile devices.

When "https" requests are captured, I am not able to get response from it.
Getting following error in System:-

```
No request was made. Possibly the SSL certificate was rejected.
Client Process: java
You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate. See SSL Proxying in the Help menu.
```

Note: I have installed charles proxy ceritificate on system and also imported certificate in Mozilla Firefox. I am able to get response for "https" from Mozilla browser on System

I have loaded charlesproxy.com/getssl on mobile. It says "Certificate is already installed on your device"

Comment: If the App whose network traffic you are trying to intercept uses Certificate Pinning approach then Charles Cert won't work in that case. Or do you face this issue with all the apps on the phone?

Comment: Oops..saw the question date after posting the above comment.Kindly ignore if you have already figured out the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

When you downloaded the certificate from charlesproxy.com/getssl, was your mobile device connected via the Charlesproxy instance that you're trying to set up?

The more recent versions of Charlesproxy create a custom certificate, so the SSL proxying setup will only work if your device was being proxied at the moment when you installed the certificate. If it wasn't, you may want to delete it and install it again while connected via Charles.

I also like to restart charles and reboot the mobile device after installing a certificate. Maybe it's superstitious, but I've had cases where the SSL calls only worked after the reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Installing ssl certificate on the device will only help with browser ssl logs, to trace ssl data of apps you will have to do the following.
Add a file res/xml/network_security_config.xml to your app:

```
<network-security-config> 
  <debug-overrides> 
    <trust-anchors> 
      <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
      <certificates src="user" /> 
    </trust-anchors> 
  </debug-overrides> 
</network-security-config>
```

Then add a reference to this file in your app's manifest, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... >
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Source: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I always had problems connecting my Personal Android phone to charles proxy despite lots of troubleshooting - I would always get errors that my network had or the error in the OP.

I went into my phone's `User Credentials` System setting.  I had 20 or so charles certs from previous attempts and other machines i've installed over the past two years - i deleted them all and things started working again. I hope that helps someone.